# Ambiguity between const best matching function and other function

Tags: c++, overloading

Let us consider following example:

```
#include <type_traits>

#if 1
struct X {};

struct O
{
    O(X) { ; }
};
#else
struct O {};

struct X
{
    operator O () { return {}; }
};
#endif

static_assert(std::is_convertible< X, O >::value);

struct S
{
    void f(X) const { ; }
    void f(O) { ; }
};

#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    S s;
    s.f(X{});
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f5b5c287fa69330)

It gives an error:

```
 error: call to member function 'f' is ambiguous
```

When I removing `const`-qualifier, then the error cease to exist. Equally the same happens, if I add `const`-qualifier to the second overloading of `f`. I.e. if both overloadings are equally `const`-qualified, then all is OK.

Why is it so?

My compiler is *clang 3.8*.

Comment: `std::declval<S&>().f(O(x))` vs `std::declval<const S&>().f(x)` (for `std::declval<S&>().f(x)`). user defined conversion versus const promotion.

Comment: @Jarod42 does it mean, that during resolution the strength of both alternatives are equally the same?

Comment: @Orient That's the definition of ambiguity.

Comment: `g` is not `const`, so when calling `f(x)`, you have to promote `this` to `const` **or** convert `x` to `O(x)`. None is better, so it is ambiguous.

Comment: @erip I think the same must be if `O` is not constructible from `X`, but `X` is implicitly convertible to `O`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member functions have implicit parameter `this`.

So to call one of the functions `f` the compiler needs either to convert `this` to type `const S *` or to convert `X` to `O`.

Neither conversion regarding all parameters is better. So the compiler issues an error.

Answer (score 2):

`Why is it so?`: The reason here is because the const-ness of the `s` object itself is *also* considered in overload resolution. Since `s` is non-const it would require adding const to the implicit `this` pointer to call the const `f`. Calling the non-const `f` is an exact match for the `this` pointer but requires an implicit conversion from `X` to `O` via O's converting constructor.

Answer (score 1):

**Mark B** & **Vlad from Moscow** answer why, I just reply how can you call them.

you should add `explicit` to avoid compiler implicit conversion

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {};

struct O
{
    explicit O(X) { ; }

    O() = default;
    O(O const &) = default;
    O(O &&) = default;
};

struct S
{
    void f(X) const { ; }
    void f(O) { ; }
};

#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.f(X{});
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT**

if your type `O` is in 3party lib
you can add a template to do this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct X {};

struct O {
    O(X) {
        ;
    }

    O() = default;
    O(O const&) = default;
    O(O&&) = default;
};

struct S {
    void f(const X) const {
        cout << "X" << endl;
    }
    void f(O) {
        cout << "O" << endl;
    }
};

#include <cstdlib>

template<typename TA, typename TB>
void myCall(TA a, TB b) {
    ((const TA &&)a).f(b);
}

template<>
void myCall(S a, O b) {
    a.f(b);
}

template<>
void myCall(S a, X b) {
    ((const S)a).f(b);
}

int main() {
    S s;
    myCall(s, X());
    //s.f(X());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `O` coming from a library code. Can't change its implementation.